# Получение параметра из дочернего объекта React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Имеется FormContainer

```
export default class FormContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.checkValidate = this.checkValidate.bind(this);
        this.write = this.write.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    checkValidate = (isValid) => {
        console.log("Parent" + isValid);
    };

    write = () => {

    };

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const elem = document.getElementById("fieldOne");
        console.log(elem);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="form-group" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <TextInput id="fieldOne" text="Строка 1" checkValidate={this.checkValidate}/>
                <TextInput id="fieldTwo" text="Строка 2" checkValidate={this.checkValidate}/>
                <button id="b" type="submit">click</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

И TextInput

```js
export default class TextInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = {
            id: "textInputId",
            type: "text",
            placeholder: "",
            text: "",
            isRequired: false
        };

    }

    test = true;

    render() {
        const {id, type, placeholder, text, isRequired} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <label htmlFor="labelTextInputId">{text}</label>
                        <input id={id} type={type} className="form-control"
                               placeholder={placeholder} required={isRequired}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Как в FormContainer получить значение поля test из TextInput? 
Хотелось бы в handleSubmit (FormContainer) получать по id значение поля test.

Answer (score 0):

Первое замечание, никогда не перезаписывайте значения пришедшие в `props`, как Вы делаете это в коде дочернего компонента:

```
this.props = {
  id: "textInputId",
  type: "text",
  placeholder: "",
  text: "",
  isRequired: false
};
```

Это очень плохой код. Относитесь к `props` иначе, Вы можете брать значения, пришедшие из `props`, но менять может их только собственник, то есть родитель. Если хотите изменить это значение - передавайте метод из родителя, который будет принимать параметр и менять знаение.

Далее есть еще замечание, если Вы используете стрелочные функции `=>` - то Вам не нужно делать `bind` в конструкторе, так как `this` уже будет проброшен в метод (для примера метод `onChange` в компоненте `TextInput` - там я вызвал метод из `props`, при этом не привязывал метод `onChange` в конструкторе).

```js
class TextInput extends React.Component {
  
  test = true;

  componentDidMount() {
    // сохраним значение поля `test` в родительском компоненте
    this.props.saveChildValue(this.props.id, this.test);
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    // простая проверка, если есть значение - `true`, иначе - `false`
    const isValid = !!e.currentTarget.value;
    // передадим в родителя текущий результат проверки
    this.props.checkValidate(isValid);
  }

  render() {
    const { id, type, placeholder, text, isRequired } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="form-row">
          <div className="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="labelTextInputId">{text}</label>
            <input
              id={id}
              type={type}
              className="form-control"
              placeholder={placeholder}
              required={isRequired}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class FormContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    // значения по-умолчанию для сохраняемых полей `test` из `TextInput`-ов
    this.state = {
      fieldOne: false,
      fieldTwo: false,
    };
  }
  
  saveChildValue = (id, value) => {
    // сохранение значения поля `test` дочернего компонента
    this.setState({ [id]: value });
  }
  
  checkValidate = (isValid) => {
    console.log("Parent: " + isValid);
  };

   write = () => {
    console.log("Write");
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = "fieldOne";
    // получаем элемент по идентификатору
    const elem = document.getElementById(id);
    // выводим в консоль значение в полученном элементе
    console.log('Input value: ', elem.value);
    // выводим сохраненное значение поля `test` дочернего компонета
    console.log('Test: ', this.state[id]);
  };
    
  render() {
    return (
      <form className="form-group" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <TextInput
          id="fieldOne"
          text="Строка 1: "
          checkValidate={this.checkValidate}
          saveChildValue={this.saveChildValue}
        />
        <TextInput
          id="fieldTwo"
          text="Строка 2: "
          checkValidate={this.checkValidate}
          saveChildValue={this.saveChildValue}
        />
        <button id="b" type="submit"> Click </button>
      </form>
  )}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FormContainer />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

По поводу получения значения поля `test` не совсем понял. Если Вы по `id` получаете элемент инпута, то Вы хотите получить текст из этого инпута или же Вы хотите получить значение из поля `test` - где хранится булево значение? Чтобы получить значение из дочернего элемента в родительском - нужно сохранить значение из дочернего элемента в родителе, к примеру на этапе монтирования компонента. Я показал пример в своем коде.